# Сгруппировать и вывести разницу между максимальным и минимальным значением

Tags: sql, oracle-study

По данным из таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES сформировать список должностей с указанием job_id, количества сотрудников, суммарной зарплаты и разницы между самой высокой и самой низкой зарплатой.

Пример таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90
```

Comment: А теперь покажите ваши попытки сделать это

Comment: select job_id, sum(salary), count(job_id), count(salary) from HR.EMPLOYEES group by job_id, salary попробовал вот так, но не понял, как вывести разницу между самой высокой и низкой зп в данной должности

Comment: Скажите, мне просто интересно, а вы по каким то соображениям не приняли ни один из ответов, который вам давали? Смотрю на вашу статистику по вопросам... Ну просто интересно, почему )

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как то не было в привычке, теперь буду отмечать)

Comment: По историческим тоже пройдитесь, что бы вопросы были закрыты. Если ответ был для вас полезен и вы использовали его, отмечайте. Если ответ не помог, то, конечно, ничего отмечать не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем данные, сгруппированные по job_id

```
select 
  job_id, 
  count(job_id) CNT_WORKER, 
  sum(salary) SALARY_ALL,
  max(salary) - min(salary) SALARY_DELTA
from HR.EMPLOYEES 
group by job_id;
```

**count** - Количество
**sum** - выводит сумму всех значений для группы
**max** - выводит максимальное значение для группы
**min** - выводит минимальное значение для группы